# Google Drive App - Database Support?

Tags: google-drive-api

What kind of database can be created to handle data in google drive ?

I want to create a google drive app where I have to save some data (text) for future manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly understand your question. You can save any file to Google Drive. So, if you want to back up a file-based database like SQLite3, you can.